# Connect IP Camera to PC directly using Ethernet cable

Tags: networking, camera, ethernet, ip-camera

I am trying to connect my IP Camera directly to my PC using Ethernet (I don't user any router). The manual guide said that I can visit the network camera via web browser by 192.168.1.64, but that is when I connect to my camera using a router.

When I run `iwconfig`, there is nothing happen with my Ethernet interface (`enp3s0f1`).

```
wlp2s0b1  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Wifi-Network"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 10:56:ED:32:19:82   
          Bit Rate=36 Mb/s   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:90  Invalid misc:730   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0f1  no wireless extensions.
```

In https://amcrest.com/forum/technical-discussion-f3/connect-ip-camera-directly-to-laptop-t1487.html, they said that I have to set up a static IP address for my PC. How can I do that?

**IP Camera**: HIKVISION (model DS-2CD2125FHWD-I)
**PC Operating System**: Arch Linux

Comment: `iwconfig`is for wireless NICs and doesn't make sense for wired Ethernet. Try `ipconfig`.

Comment: There is no `ipconfig` in Linux. Did you mean `ifconfig`? How to do that with `ifconfig`?

Comment: Yes, `ifconfig` is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the Ethernet NIC like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/netctl/enp0s3

Description='NIC to camera'
Interface=enp0s3
Connection=ethernet
IP=static
Address=('192.168.1.10/24')`
```

(save)

```
sudo netctl start enp0s3
```

For a full description, check https://www.ostechnix.com/configure-static-dynamic-ip-address-arch-linux/